# Parsing a C++ string into a tuple

Tags: c++, parsing, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am working on a simple CSV parser that would store the lines of a file in a tuple. This would be an easy task if it wasn't for the fact that the number of entries on the lines inside the file is a variable, as well as their type. Thus, the lines could be like that:

1,2.2,hello,18,world

The parser should be able to work like this:

```
ifstream file("input.csv");
SimpleCSVParser<int, float, string, int, string> parser(file);
```

Things get complex when I try to implement a function to parse the actual line. I still have not found a way to extract the next type from the parameter list to declare the variable before calling `file >> var` on it. I would also need to do this in a loop, somehow constructing a tuple from the results of each iteration.

So how do I parse the string into a tuple using plain C++11?
I tried this:

```
template <typename ...Targs>
tuple<Targs...> SimpleCSVParser<Targs...>::iterator::operator*() {
    istringstream in(cur);
    in.imbue(locale(locale(), new commasep)); // for comma separation
    tuple<Targs...> t;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Targs); ++i) {
        tuple_element<i,decltype(t)>::type first;
        in >> first;
        auto newt = make_tuple(first);
        // what do I do here?
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work since the tuple I use to extract types is empty.

Comment: show your not-working parser please

Comment: @Roberto updated the post

Comment: `tuple_element<i,decltype(t)>` requires a `constexpr` `i`, not a run-time variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, you try to iterate over tuple indices/types which doesn't work, I think. What you *can* do, however, is to just call a read function for each member. The idea is to delegate processing of the tuple to a function which uses a parameter pack to expand an operation to an operation on each element. `std::index_sequence<...>` can be used to get the sequence of integers.

Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool read_tuple_element(std::istream& in, T& value) {
    in >> value;
    return true;
}

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
void read_tuple_elements(std::istream& in, Tuple& value, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    std::initializer_list<bool>{ read_tuple_element(in, std::get<I>(value))... });
}

template <typename ...Targs>
tuple<Targs...> SimpleCSVParser<Targs...>::iterator::operator*() {
    std::istringstream in(cur);
    in.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new commasep)); // for comma separation
    std::tuple<Targs...> t;
    read_tuple_elements(in, t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Targs)>{});
    if (in) { // you may want to check if all data was consumed by adding && in.eof()
        // now do something with the filled t;
    }
    else {
        // the value could *not* successfully be read: somehow deal with that
    }
}
```

The basic idea of the above code is simply to create a suitable sequence of calls to `read_tuple_element()`. Before jumping into the generic code, assume we'd want to implement reading of a `std::tuple<T0, T1, T2> value` with just three elements. We could implement the read using (using `rte()` instead of `read_tuple_element()` for brevity):

```
rte(get<0>(value)), rte(get<1>(value)), rte(get<2>(value));
```

Now, instead of writing this out for each number of elements, if we had an index sequence `std::size_t... I` we could get this sequence [nearly] using

```
rte(get<I>(value))...;
```

It isn't allowed to expand a parameter pack like this, though. Instead, the parameter pack needs to be put into some context. The code above uses a `std::initializer_list<bool>` for this purpose: the elements of a `std::initializer_list<T>` are constructed in the order listed. That is, we got

```
std::initializer_list<bool>{ rte(get<I>(value))... };
```

The missing bit is how to create the parameter pack `I` evaluating to a sequence of suitable indices. Conveniently, the standard library defines `std::make_index_sequence<Size>` which creates a `std::index_sequence<I...>` with a sequence of values for `I` as `0, 1, 2, ..., Size-1`. So, calling `read_tuple_elements()` with `std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Targs){}` creates an object with a suitable list of arguments which can be deduced and then used to expand the tuple into a sequence of elements passed to `read_tuple_element()`.

Comment: The following line won't compile, stating 'expression contains unexpanded parameter pack': `dummy(read_tuple_element(in, std::get<I>(value)));`

Comment: Adding ... after `std::get<I>(value))...);` did fix the error. I still don't completely understand why we need the dummy function, though. Could you please briefly explain its purpose?

Comment: Thank you! The code indeed does what I wanted. Now I guess I'll try to figure out how and why that works.

Comment: @DmitrySerov: OK, I have added some explanation (and I'll remove the comments from this answer soon avoid having it look messy...).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use tuples like this.

> This would be an easy task if it wasn't for the fact that the number
>   of entries on the lines inside the file is a variable, as well as
>   their type.

If I understand, you only know your wanted tuples size and types at run-time while processing your file. Unfortunately this must be known at compile-time...

If you really want to use tuples, you have to make a pre treatment on your file to determine the data size and types. Then you can use the right tuples accordingly. But you cannot do that directly.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method to do something like this via [type erasure](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/type-erasure-part-i/), for example using a `union` of all possible value types plus a flag indicating which is the actual entry

```
namespace generic_type {
  struct generic
  {
    enum type { Void=0, Bool=1, Int=2, String=3, Float=4 };
    type Type=Void;
    union {
      bool B;
      std::int64_t I;
      std::string S;
      double X;
    }
    generic() = default;
    generic(generic&&) = default;
    generic(generic const&) = default;
    generic(bool b) : Type(Bool), B(b) {}
    generic(std::int64_t i) : Type(Int), I(i) {}
    generic(std::uint64_t i) : Type(Int), I(i) {}
    generic(std::string const&s) : Type(String), S(s) {}
    generic(std::string &&s) : Type(String), S(std::move(s)) {}
    generic(double x) : Type(Float), X(x) {}
  };

  namespace details {// auxiliary stuff
    template<typename T, typename E=void>
    struct traits
    {
      static constexpr generic::type Type=generic::Void;
      static void get(generic const&) {}
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<bool,void>
    {
      static constexpr generic::type Type=generic::Bool;
      static bool get(generic const&x) { return x.B; }
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct traits<T,enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>
    {
      static constexpr generic::type Type=generic::Int;
      static T get(generic const&x) { return x.I; }
    };

    template<>
    struct traits<std::string,void>
    {
      static constexpr generic::type Type=generic::Str;
      static std::string const& get(generic const&x) { return x.S; }
      static std::string&& get(generic&&x) { return std::move(x.S); }
    };

    template<T>
    struct traits<float,enable_if<std::is_same<T,float>::value ||
                                  std::is_same<T,double>::value>
    {
      static constexpr generic::type Type=generic::Float; };
      static T get(generic const&x) { return x.X; }
    }
  }

  template<typename T>
  auto unsafe_extract(generic const&x)
  -> decltype(details::traits<T>::get(x))
  { return details::traits<T>::get(x); }

  template<typename T>
  auto unsafe_extract(generic&&x)
  -> decltype(details::traits<T>::get(std::move(x)))
  { return details::traits<T>::get(std::move(x)); }

  template<typename T>
  auto extract(generic const&x)
  -> decltype(unsafe_extract(x))
  {
    if(details::traits<T>::Type != x.Type)
      throw std::runtime_error("type mismatch in extract(generic)");
    return unsafe_extract(x);
  }

  template<typename T>
  auto extract(generic&&x)
  -> decltype(unsafe_extract(std::move(x)))
  {
    if(details::traits<T>::Type != x.Type)
      throw std::runtime_error("type mismatch in extract(generic&&)");
    return unsafe_extract(std::move(x));
  }
}
using generic_type::generic;
```

and then you can store your data in a `std::vector<generic>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Targs); ++i) {
    tuple_element<i,decltype(t)>::type first;
    in >> first;
    auto newt = make_tuple(first);
    // what do I do here?
}
```

This is runtime. You should consider using recursive functions using variadic templates. That would be compile time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [std::tuple_cat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) you should be able to add each subsequent value to the tuple. I would also reccommend using C++14 return type deduction if I were you it eliminates the need to know the return type.